# How do I set up automatic updates via the source code in my Android Studio app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I set up automatic updates via the source code in my Android Studio app?
The app is not in the PlayStore.

Comment: Better to publish it on the play store, if you want to publish it for free use the galaxy store, mi store, etc they are all free. Otherwise, you will have to create an update checker inside your app, and then if you have to update, download the apk and then install it. On the later method if you need any help tell me.

Comment: And also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

- Setting up a website that contains the most recent version and apk to download, then in code scraping the website or just using an API to get the lastest version and compare it with the installed version
- Publishing your app to the play store / galaxy store / mi store / other websites that are willing to publish your app  (way easier)